# Estimate $\ln\left( 1.04^{0.25} + 0.98^{0.2} -1 \right)$ with 2D Taylor

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, estimation

I need to estimate $\ln\left( 1.04^{0.25} + 0.98^{0.2} -1 \right)$ with a Taylor approximation of a two variable function (i.e. x and y).

Eventually I managed to pull the (presumably) correct function:
$$f(x,y) = \ln \left( (1+2x)^{\frac{5}{4}y} - (1-x)^y - 1 \right)$$
around $\left( 0, 0.2 \right)$.

But its partial derivatives are overly complicated, see examples for [$f_{xx}$ and $f_{yx}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2%29%20%28ln%28%20%281%2B2x%29%5E%285y%2F4%29%20%2B%20%281-x%29%5Ey%20-1%20%29%29%2C%20%28d%5E2%2Fdydx%29%20%28ln%28%20%281%2B2x%29%5E%285y%2F4%29%20%2B%20%281-x%29%5Ey%20-1%20%29%29).
So my best guess for the function is wrong. It feels like I'm missing an identity that would simplify the task.

Could you please direct my towards the most appropriate function?

Comment: It is better to use $ln((1+x)^{.25}+(1-y)^.2-1)$.  Making the exponents into variable is overly complicated.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that you complicate things too much. Just try $f(x,y)=\ln (x^{0.25} + y^{0.02} -1)$ around $(1,1)$.